# Rewrite all sub directories except a few select paths

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-location

So if I have current setup like this.

```
domain.com/some-path/
domain.com/some-path/locations/
domain.com/some-path/locations/some-location
domain.com/some-path/locations/locb
domain.com/some-path/locations/infinite-location-list
```

Those are the URL patterns I don't want to rewrite. The `some-path` sub-directory, it's child `locations` sub-directory, and anything under `locations`.

All other child URLs under the `some-path` directory should be 301 directed to the `/some-path/` directory.

I tried something like this:

```
location ~* ^/some-path/(.+)? {

  if ($request_uri !~ "^/some-path/locations/(.*)$") {
    return 301 http://domain.com/some-path/;
  }

}
```

But `/some-path/` gets stuck in a redirect loop, and `/some-path/locations/` throws a server side nginx 404.

Thoughts on how to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***This is a bad idea, design-wise.***  If a user mistypes `domain.com/some-path/locations/some-location`, which is valid, according to you, as `domain.com/some-path/location/some-location`, which is not valid, then they'll end up having all of their typing wiped out, and they'll have to start from scratch (or maybe just go to your competitor).

However, if you so insist for a regular expression:

```
    if ($request_uri !~ "^/some-path/($|locations/.*$)") {
        return 301 http://domain.com/some-path/;
    }
```

You'll probably have to have this within an existing `location`, or even keep it at the top level, depending on the rest of your config, since only a single `location` gets to handle a given request.

Comment: Totally agree with you on the design aspect. I am actually pushing back on this request. This section/sub-directory of the site requires a massive amount of rewrite/redirects that is just completely inefficient to write individually. This was going to be my fallback solution in case I lose this battle.

Comment: @Nathan, well, there is nothing wrong with crazy rewrites -- checkout http://mdoc.su/, it's open-source on my github, too -- just as long as the user experience goes up, not down. :-)